# How do I bind to a target property of a dynamically created form control in angular 7?

Tags: angular

I want to bind to the target property of a dynamically created form control in angular.  How do I do this?  Here is what I have currently, which works correctly for one form control named `filingStatus`:

```html
<drop-down-with-label
     [formGroup]="controlContainer.control"
     [options]="dropDown.stateTaxOptions"
     [validationLogic]="{ notvalid: this.formGroup.controls.filingStatus.invalid }"
></drop-down-with-label>
```

But I need it to work for a dynamically named form control.  Here is ideally what I'd like to be able to do, but this syntax doesnt work:

```html
<drop-down-with-label
     [formGroup]="controlContainer.control"
     [options]="dropDown.stateTaxOptions"
     [validationLogic]="{ notvalid: this.formGroup.controls." + dropDown.name +  ".invalid }"
></drop-down-with-label>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use `[validationLogic]="expression"`, the expresion is validate, That's
`this.formGroup.controls.filingStatus.invalid` is replace by the property invalid of the control. So I suppose you need write

```
[validationLogic]="{ notvalid: this.formGroup.get('dropDown.name').invalid }"
```

Comment: In general, this is the correct answer, but what I had to do was this:  [validationLogic]="{ notvalid: this.formGroup.get(this.getControlName(dropDown)).invalid }"

Comment: getControlName(control) {
    return control.name.toLowerCase();
  }

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not use double quotes like that but anyway...

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) `_.get` function for that like this:

In your component add lodash (typically as `_`) like:

```
 _ = _;
```

And in your template:

```
<drop-down-with-label
 [formGroup]="controlContainer.control"
 [options]="dropDown.stateTaxOptions"
 [validationLogic]="{ notvalid: _.get(this.formGroup.controls,'dropDown.name.invalid') }"
```

> 

Comment: Curiosity, why use lodash? I think it's not necesary